# JS: where do you instantiate functions that return another function?

Tags: javascript

I am making an infinite scroll and the first thing I did was attach an eventListener to detect when the scroll is near-bottom and if so, fire `scrollLoader()`

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + 100 >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            scrollLoader();
        }
    })
```

- I made the `scrollLoader` function below that , for right now, uses a setTimeout to simulate an asynchronous fetch until I have an endpoint. The function returns a function so that `loadingData` is not on the global scope.

  ```
    function checkScroll() {
        let loadingData;

        return function() {    
            if (loadingData) {
                return
            }
            loadingData = true;
            new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve()
                }, 5000)
            })
            .then(() => {
                loadingData = false;
            })
        }
    }
  ```

So I would need to instantiate `scrollLoader` since it returns a function and replace it with the of the variable:

`const detectScroll = scrollLoader()`

and edit the eventListener to call this now instead of `scrollLoader()` directly:

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + 100 >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            detectScroll();
        }
    })
```

Where exactly do I put this line in my code though ( `const detectScroll = scrollLoader()`  ) ?  Anywhere I put it seems out of place since it's just there to instantiate once.

Comment: You might be making this more difficult than it needs to be. Is there some reason loadingData can't exist in the global scope? If it doesn't exist in the global scope, then you at least need to pass it as a parameter to checkScroll(); otherwise, the function will always be executed with a falsy value for loadingData, since the variable is instantiated in the function itself.

Comment: well it's a closure so that's why if it's instantiated once, the variable value will exist in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the *only* spot this code will ever be used, this is the perfect time to use an Immediate Invoked Function Expression (IIFE):

Note the syntax: `(()=>{ ... })();`

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + 100 >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
   let loadingData;
   (() => {
      if (loadingData) {
        return
      }
      loadingData = true;
      new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
          }, 5000)
        })
        .then(() => {
          loadingData = false;
        })
    })();
  }
})
```

Comment: interesting, thanks!  what about if I didn't use the IFFE though?  Where in the code should the instantiation exist?

Comment: Are you looking to do it your way or to learn and follow best practices? As a side note, you don't _instantiate_ functions, you _call_ or _invoke_ them. But, if you looking to do things your way, take up more memory and waste CPU cycles, replace the IIFE with your function call, you could actually do `scrollLoader()()` given your code above. That would work.